# Cannot get react application to run to do "could not determine executable to run"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npx

I just started a basic react tutorial on React, and I am just starting out with this language. Everything was fine last night...I was able to get my application to run. However I think I might have done something I should not have which was delete everything with in my src directory instead of the index.js folder (I thought the tutorial stated that all i needed just that file?). [the src directory for my react app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbHHA.png). I had the browser output of the application running successfully while making updates to my index.js file, however I closed out of that window. Now when I start my application i keep getting this error: [error when running application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZGt3.png). I look at the log file, and I get the following:

0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\ultim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@10.1.0
2 info using node@v20.6.1
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 2ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 3ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\ultim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 5ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 5ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\ultim\my-react-app.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 2ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\ultim.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\ultim\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load Completed in 13ms
17 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 13ms
18 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 0ms
20 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 1ms
21 verbose title npm exec start
22 verbose argv "exec" "--" "start"
23 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
24 timing npm:load:display Completed in 2ms
25 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\ultim\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-09-10T15_47_01_375Z-
26 verbose logfile C:\Users\ultim\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-09-10T15_47_01_375Z-debug-0.log
27 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 11ms
28 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
29 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
30 timing npm:load Completed in 63ms
31 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
32 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files
33 silly logfile done cleaning log files
34 verbose shrinkwrap failed to load node_modules/.package-lock.json out of date, updated: node_modules
35 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/start 385ms (cache revalidated)
36 timing command:exec Completed in 1901ms
37 verbose stack Error: could not determine executable to run
37 verbose stack     at getBinFromManifest (C:\Users\ultim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\libnpmexec\lib\get-bin-from-manifest.js:17:23)
37 verbose stack     at exec (C:\Users\ultim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\libnpmexec\lib\index.js:188:15)
37 verbose stack     at async module.exports (C:\Users\ultim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli-entry.js:61:5)
38 verbose pkgid start@5.1.0
39 verbose cwd C:\Users\ultim\my-react-app
40 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19045
41 verbose node v20.6.1
42 verbose npm  v10.1.0
43 error could not determine executable to run
44 verbose exit 1
45 timing npm Completed in 2432ms
46 verbose code 1.

One source stated updating node.js & npm, which i did. I am unsure what to make of this error...am I missing critical files in my project source?

I tried updating node.js and npm to the current version.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.